# We want to add a function length() to the class Node that implements user defined lists which will compute the length of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def length(self):
    if self.value == None:
        return(0)
    elif self.next == None:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(***)?
```

Comment: Please use a short and informative title for your question and add the explanation to the body. Also, explain what's the problem and your efforts towards solving it.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the length recursively:

1. For an empty `Node` (a node with `value == None`), the length is `0`, as you already defined.
2. For a non empty Node, the length is 1 plus the length of the next `Node`:

```
 def length(self):
    if self.value == None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + self.next.length()
```

Comment: Beside the mysterious way that you could guess OP's problem how did you know you should call the `next` method? Or even the way it's implemented?

Comment: @Kasramvd OP is clearly attempting to implement a linked list. `next` shouldn't be a method call, though (edited and fixed, thanks) - it's an attribute, as can be seen in the OP's code.